# Mysql Group by Having

Tags: mysql

I have a Table:

```
id  ip              count   time                city      country

1   217.165.93.78   1   2013-08-05 02:24:10     DUBAI     UNITED ARAB EMIRATES

2   122.178.229.243 1   2013-08-06 02:25:37     BANGALORE INDIA

3   27.97.27.185    1   2013-08-06 02:26:48     PUNE      INDIA

4   217.165.93.78   1   2013-08-06 02:39:12     DUBAI     UNITED ARAB EMIRATES
```

I need to get result on grouping ip based on dates.

Comment: please provide your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I got your question right, but how about

```
select DATE_FORMAT(time, '%d-%m-%Y'), ip 
from testtable
group by DATE(time), ip;
```

but please provide expected result example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/201ac6/7

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what exactly you want. and you didnt show your wished result , then i guess you want this

```
     select `id`, `ip`, count(*) count , `time`, `city`, `country` from table1
     group by ip
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8de83/3)

if you want check by dates

```
   select `id`, `ip`, count(*) count , `time`, `city`, `country` from table1
   where DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-08-05'
   group by ip
```

Answer (score -2):

try using: group by Convert(varchar(10),time,103)